# Не отвечать на сканирование портов с помощью iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Стоит задача - защититься от сканирования сети (например, nmap) с помощью средств iptables. Все icmp пакеты закрыть нельзя, поэтому сейчас прописано так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И правило, которое блокирует все остальные типы icmp, по списку расположено ниже. Теперь надо блокировать tcp соединения, с ними возникла проблема. Правил прописано много, но ничего не помогает. Подскажите, что не так?
И правильно ли я понимаю, что под правило FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE попадают все tcp-пакеты и должно происходить дроп всех соединений?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]